# Arduino Yun Wifi Sketch Upload not working on OS X Yosemite

Tags: arduino-yun

I'm trying to upload a sketch to my Arduino Yun over Wifi and it is not working. I'm running OS X 10.10.3 with Java 1.8.0_25 and Arduino IDE version 1.6.4.

I can upload the sketch via USB, but when I try using WiFi I see the following error in the Arduino Console:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SSHUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SSHUploader.java:102)
at processing.app.debug.Compiler.upload(Compiler.java:163)
at processing.app.Sketch.upload(Sketch.java:1220)
at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1194)
at processing.app.Sketch.exportApplet(Sketch.java:1166)
at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2487)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.openChannel(Session.java:843)
at cc.arduino.packages.ssh.SSH.execSyncCommand(SSH.java:58)
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SSHUploader.runAVRDude(SSHUploader.java:130)
at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SSHUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SSHUploader.java:93)
... 6 more
```

I've found some related information on [github](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/1587) and [arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=203256.0), but I can't quite see how it applies to my setup or any documentation on instructions for setting up ~/.ssh/config.

I am able to connect to my board using SSH from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the Arduino Forum topic](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=203256.0), I had a ~/.ssh/config file with a ServerAliveInterval value set. The wifi upload worked as soon as I removed this.